# MySQL Query for Stock Level Process

Tags: mysql, jsp, stock

I am doing an inventory management system rn and found a dead end on how i should do on my stock increases and decreases.

heres the thing,
if i ordered from supplier and set the stock status to "Ordered" the stock will remain unchanged and once I change the status to "Received" the quantity of product/stock i have order will be automatically added to my inventory table.

Where and how should i make to make this happened. my lecturer said smth about having a trigger. and i really dont know how to start. please give some input on how i should start. thanks in advance.

i'm using Tomcat 8.0, MySQL and JSP.

Comment: How do you change the order status to Received?  If there's code involved, then that's the place to update your Inventory table.

Comment: using update query, one of the clerk/admin can change the status to "Received". once it changed. the quantity will be increases and updated to the database.